# ERROR CS0117 ('Debug' does not contain a definition for 'log')

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, visual-studio-code

Im trying to show on console when a gameobject collides with another gameobject with collide. I keep getting this error on unity's console ERROR CS0117, 'Debug' does not contain a definition for 'log'.

- im on mac using .net core
- im using vs code 1.35.1
  and unity 2019.3.0a5
- i already have all the usings that i need, but intellisense does not find a definition for my debug or for anything whatsoever, this is frustrating :/
- i dont have any other .cs file named debug neither

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

  public class DeadZone : MonoBehaviour
  {
      private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
          Debug.log("Collision");
      }

      private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
          Debug.log("Trigger");
      }
  }
  ```

i expect a "collision" message in the console of unity when my ball gameobject touches a wall gameobject, both with collider but i only get that error within the console, i also already tried using UnityEngine.Debug.log(); but havent got any success yet... :(

Comment: Debug.Log(""); ?

Comment: Method names in C# _almost always_ start with a capital letter.

Comment: most coding is about attention to detail.. when you're newer at things people dont realise the difference between something and someThing, or SomeThing.. counting of braces and the different types, positioning of variables and methods..

Answer (score 9):

You are using `Debug.log()`. but you should be using `Debug.Log()`. Notice the capitalised "L" on "Log".

By naming convention for C# method names will always start with a capital letter.

If you look at the [Unity Docs for Debug.Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) you'll also see in the code examples/title that it uses the capital L

Also judging from your tags you are using Visual Studio. Make sure that intelliSense is turned on, as this should detect and most of the time even automatically fix these kinds of typos for you.

Comment: wow, cant see how much of a headache i got just for forgetting that basic rule... Thanks man. you are the real MVP not khawi hahaha

Comment: also, how can i turn on intellisense, i already have installed the c# extension that pressumably comes with intellisense. I have read that my proyect has to have a .json file for intellisense to work, but im working with unity scripts so i dont have that file in my folder...

Comment: @VTORRES5 It should be turned on by default, however you can check the manpage here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019 for more info on it. Also please accept the answer if this helped solve your issue, so it can help people in the future :)

Comment: [10:48:33] Assetx\GridManager.cs(38,33): error 'Debug' does not contain a definition for 'Log' --> My line is: Debug.Log("Hello");

Comment: [10:48:33] Assetx\GridManager.cs(38,33): error 'Debug' does not contain a definition for 'Log' --> My line is: Debug.Log("Hello");
Changed (edit): UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Hi"); --> Works?
using UnityEngine: <<< Why does this not allow: Debug.Log then? Coming from 'C' Lang background this makes zero sense to me.

Comment: @ejbytes Do you happen to also have `using System.Diagnostics` in your project? If there is another namespace that implements the `Log` functionality it will conflict and not be able to use either. (which would explain `UnityEngine.Debug.Log` working, as you then define from which namespace to pull the `Log` functionality)

Comment: @Remy - I'm Super Noob to C#. I am using System.Diagnostics, should I remove it? It might have "installed dependency" while trying another fail at something else? I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ejbytes if you're not using the `System.Diagnostics` namespace (e.g. `Stopwatch`) then yes, remove it. If you *are* using something specific from `Diagnostics` then just define it as `UnityEngine.Debug.Log`. Namespaces are a way to organise and seperate classes/functions etc that you then import with the `using` keyword. In this case `UnityEngine` and `System.Diagnostics` both implement a funciton called `Debug`. Having both in your `using` is pretty much the same as having two `Debug` functions in your code. Thus you need to define which one you want to use. E.g `UnityEngine.Debug`

Comment: @Remy - Ah, I see. Hence the more detailed error, "Ambigious use of Debug... Diagnostics and UnityEngine". Makes sense now. Thanks!