# Unity Error: Debug does not contain definition for log. Coding In Visual Studio Code, also installed required packets but still not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode for Unity but, cannot run the program as it gives error:
"Debug does not contain definition for log"
Below code given

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

void Start()
{

Debug.log("Welcome to Number Wizard");

Debug.log("Pick a Number and don't tell me what it is");

Debug.log("The highest number you can pick is 1000");

Debug.log("The lowest number u can pick is 1");

}

// Update is called once per frame

void Update()
{

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debug-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679450/error-cs0117-debug-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-log)

Comment: `Debug.Log` ist a **capital `L`**